# Difference between Office 365 preview and sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am new to sharepoint online. At first I need to know the difference between sharepoint online and office 365 preview.

Preview site:  https://portal.microsoftonline.com/Admin/Default.aspx which looms like below.

[image]

I have also the below site

[image]

Now what is the difference between the two. My goal is to create apps and webparts. Which one shall i choose? I have not installed sharepoint 2013 server/ sharepoint foundation. Can i create apps and webparts without installing server2013/foundation2013?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Office365 Preview is running on the new SharePoint 2013 platform. If you want to build and monetize apps/web parts, you would need to go with this option, as it is the 
latest and greatest.

Go to http://dev.office.com to get all of the resources you need including links to the software, tutorials, documentation, etc...

Microsoft provides a free Office365 portal specifically for developers who want to build apps on the online platform. With this, all you would need is Visual Studio 2012 and the SharePoint/Office SDK installed to build apps. You would deploy and debug directly on the online portal without needing SharePoint installed on your environment.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Eric what you have said that is absolutely correct.But,Is this possible to add web service and class files to solution in vs2012.?If i add any files those are not applying to my online account application.please give me possible reply..i want to bind data from sql server to Excel.

Comment: Hey shankar. Try taking sitename.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc. Might be what you're looking for. I haven't been able to authenticate myself yet, though.